# Codeigniter .htaccess file for SSL inserts index.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

I'm using the following .htaccess file to redirect certain pages to `https://`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (sale|success|cancel)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(static|sale|success|cancel)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|static)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works, except that when you go to the page that gets rewritten to `https://` it also inserts `index.php` in the URL. Everything works fine, but I would like that `index.php` not to be inserted. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `L` flag from your top 2 rules.

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (sale|success|cancel) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(static|sale|success|cancel) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|static) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Test in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory "/home/test">
    Require all granted
    ***AllowOverride All***
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
```

After adding "AllowOverride All" in your apache configuration, it will work properly.

Regards.